# How to set Font of String Taken from Resource bundle in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I'm giving localization support in my app in blackberry.Now the problem is i want to use system font in my application but the hieght should be constant.Now i want to use Status.show method to show some string on the screen.The string is coming from the resource bundle.

So kindly suggest how to set the font of that.

Thanx in advance

Regards

Deepak Goel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class DialogBox extends PopupScreen implements FieldChangeListener {
    private ButtonField okButton = new ButtonField("OK", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
    private static DialogBox dialog = null;

    private DialogBox( String text) {
        super(new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR));
        add(new LabelField(text, Field.FIELD_HCENTER));
        okButton.setChangeListener(this);
        add(okButton);
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        super.paint(graphics);
    }

    public static void show(String text) {
        dialog = new BMDialogBox(text);
        Thread threadToRun = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(dialog);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    throw new RuntimeException("Exception detected while waiting: " +     t.toString());
                }
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(dialog);
                } catch (Exception e) { }
                });
        }
    };
    threadToRun.start();
}
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(dialog);
                } catch (Exception e) { }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: BMDialogBox(text); is this your class

Comment: yes, this class' name was BMDialogBox, i have changed that to DialogBox. at one line i've missed changing. now i corrected that.

You should use this code like this:
`DialogBox.show ("something");`

Answer (score 0):

you can set a fields font with original style of it and given height(15) just like that:

```
setFont(getFont().derive(getFont().getStyle(),15));
```

Comment: Ya Thanx for your response but my problem is how we can use it with Status.show() method.As by default it is showing the System font

Comment: as far as i know Status.show() method behaves like a Dialog.inform() method. The difference is the timer that status has. I think you could use custom Popup Screen,put timer on it and show whatever you want. You can put some field and change font by using this answers code.

Comment: Ya thnx...I was i also thinking the same...kindly provide me a sample code for creating custom class for popup screen,

Comment: i think, in my application i need this custom popup screen that i mentioned. If i do that i will post it as an answer.